# Can any flat-space QFT be made Weyl invariant on curved space using curvature coupling?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, classical-field-theory

I seem to have an argument that any theory defined on flat spacetime can be extended to a theory on general spacetimes which is Weyl-invariant, by carefully choosing the curvature coupling. I wonder if I made a mistake somewhere.

Consider a classical scalar field $\phi$ defined on a general curved background. Don't assume anything about its action $S$. I'll adopt the following defintion of the stress tensor:
$$\tag{1}T^{ab} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{g}}\frac{\delta S}{\delta g_{ab}}.$$
Then, under a small Weyl rescaling $g\to e^{2\omega}g$, the action varies as
$$\tag{2} \delta_\omega S = \int d^dx \sqrt{g} \omega T^a_a.$$

Now, define a new action by
$$\tag{3} \tilde{S} = S + \int d^d x\sqrt{g} X R$$
where $X$ is some quantity involving $\phi$ and $R$ is the Ricci scalar. When $R=0$ we have $\tilde{S}=S$, so the theories are physically equivalent on flat spacetime.  But the stress-energy tensors will be different. In particular, perturbing around flat spacetime with a small Weyl-rescaling $\eta \to e^{2\omega}\eta$, we will have
\begin{align}\tag{4} 
    \delta_\omega \int d^d x\sqrt{g} XR  &=  \int d^d x \sqrt{g} X \delta_\omega R \newline
    &= -2(d-1)\int d^dx \sqrt{g} X\partial^2 \omega \newline
    &= -2(d-1)\int d^dx \sqrt{g} \omega \partial^2 X.
\end{align}
In the first line I used the fact $R=0$ on flat spacetime; in the second, I used the conformal transformation of the Ricci scalar given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Levi-Civita_connection); in the third I integrated by parts twice (taking $\omega$ to be compactly supported so surface terms vanish).

Hence the new stress-energy tensor corresponding to $\tilde{S}$ has trace given by
$$\tilde{T}^a_a = T^a_a - 2(d-1) \partial^2 X .$$

Now just choose $X$ such that the RHS equals zero. I think this is always possible: we're just solving a sourced wave equation. So the theory corresponding to $\tilde{S}$ agrees with the original $S$-theory on flat spacetime, and has traceless stress-energy tensor on flat spacetime.

Is this correct? It seems surprising if true. Note that I never assumed the action $S$ was conformally invariant or anything...

Comment: Allowing $X$ to be a non-local functional of $\phi$, you might be right.

Comment: That is called Ricci gauging, see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9607110#:~:text=Scale%2Dinvariant%20actions%20in%20arbitrary,global%20Weyl%2Dgroup%20is%20gauged.)